# iphone: find date for 4th day of week

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, date

I used NSDateComponents to find date for 4th, 2nd day of the week like this

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit |
                                                                 NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                                                 NSYearCalendarUnit |
                                                                 NSWeekCalendarUnit | 
                                                                 NSWeekdayCalendarUnit)
                                                       fromDate:today];
[weekdayComponents setWeekday:4];


NSLog(@"Date at that day was %@",[gregorian dateFromComponents:weekdayComponents]);
```

but every time the output is

> Date at that day was 2011-06-20 18:30:00 +0000

Can you help in this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[weekdayComponents setDay:weekdayComponents.day+ (4-weekdayComponents.weekday)];
```

As for the NSlog output: NSLog (@"%@", somedate) displays the time in GMT0, but actions with NSDateComponents made taking into account time zone, so 2011-06-20 18:30:00 +0000 is beginning оf 21.06.2011 in your time zone